# Error when accessing a AngularJs service method which uses $resource

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

i'm new to angularjs and trying to access a service method which uses $resource to make a call to my rest api. But when i'm trying to access its giving a error. also when i try to access a method which does not use $resource it works fine.

here's my code.

```
app.factory('userService', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {        
        var factory = {};

        factory.authenticatedUser;

        factory.test = function(){
            return "Test";
        };

        factory.getLoggedInUser = function(){ 
            $resource('api/user', {}, {
                query: {method: 'GET'}
            });
        };

        factory.getAuthenticatedUser = function(){
                return factory.authenticatedUser;
        };

        factory.setAuthenticatedUser = function(user){
                factory.authenticatedUser = user;
        };

        return factory;
    }]);
```

here's how i'm trying to access the method.

```
userService.getLoggedInUser.query(function(loggedInUser) { 

});
```

this throws the following error.

```
TypeError: userService.getLoggedInUser.query is not a function
```

but this works fine.

```
var text = userService.test();
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: `getLoggedInUser` is a function. Why do you think it has a field named `query` of type function?

Comment: i'm at the starting point with angular and have no clue on how to fix this. what my requirement is to store the logged in user object inside the service so i can retrieve it for later use.

Comment: That doesn't have much to do with angular. You're trying to access an attribute that doesn't exist. getLoggedInUser is a function you defined. It has no query attribute. Note that you're never *calling* the function. Also note that, even if you called it, it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a $ sign. And return the $resource object from your function

```
factory.getLoggedInUser = function(){ 
        return $resource('api/user', {}, {
            query: {method: 'GET'}
        });
    };

userService.getLoggedInUser().$query(function(loggedInUser) { 
});
```

Comment: tried it out but it still gives the same error. TypeError: userService.getLoggedInUser.$query is not a function

Comment: You mean `userService.getLoggedInUser().$query(...)`, right? Note the difference between accessing an attribute of a function, and accessing an attribute of the  object returned by a function.

Comment: @JBNizet True, I actually did not catch that... Fixed now.

Comment: Still getting the same error guys. 
TypeError: userService.getLoggedInUser.$query is not a function. i added the modification to return the $resource object but still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you see the addition of the () too?
`userService.getLoggedInUser().$query`